# Lua strings 'n' things

Tags: string, lua

New to Lua, need to check if a string exists inside another string, and can't seem to figure it out, how do I?

In PHP this'd be:

```
<?php
$pos = strpos($haystack,$needle);

if($pos === false) {
 // string needle NOT found in haystack
} else {
 // string needle found in haystack
}
?>
```

Also need to chop off the last char of a string...

Comment: In the future, if you ever have more trouble with lua strings, this is a very good resource: http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringRecipes

Answer (score 4):

http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial

```
print(string.find("foobar", "foo"))
```

yields...

```
1   3
```

---

```
print(string.find("foobar", "baz"))
```

yields...

```
nil
```

---

```
print(string.sub("foobar", 1, 5))
```

yields...

```
fooba
```

Comment: If you're looking for the plain substring (and not a pattern), it is a good idea to disable the pattern handling by passing true as a fourth argument to `string.find`. This way you will not have to escape the string. `string.find("foobar", "foo", nil, true)`

Answer (score 0):

For chopping the last character, you can use a negative index:

```
string.sub("the string.", 1, -2)
```